# Image cropped by rmagick has black bar at bottom in Safari

Tags: css, imagemagick, rmagick

I have an image that has been cropped by rmagick. On Firefox and Chrome, it looks fine but on Safari (12.0.3 running on OSX 10.13.6) there is a black bar along the bottom. Here's two screen shots:

## Firefox and Chrome

[image: Firefox and chrome]

## Safari

[image: Safari]

It looks like there is some empty space at the bottom of the image and Firefox/Chrome are making it transparent while Safari is making it black. (Forgive me if my terminology is off, I'm not a graphic designer).

I can't show the particular code because it proprietary, but any help understanding how to go about fixing the problem generally would be appreciated.

Alternatively, if you can better help me understand the specific problem, that would be great too.

Comment: What version of Safari? What version of OSX? Please always be specific about your environment

Comment: @fmw42 updated to include Safari and OSX versions.

Comment: How did you crop it? What was the command? What was the output format? If you did not add +repage after -crop or -trim and have an output PNG or TIFF, then try adding that. Your issue is likely that you left the virtual-canvas in the image and that is what you are seeing. It would help if you provide your actual input image and your command line.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to generate this image?